# Elasticsearch bulk import from mongodb

Tags: elasticsearch

How to import data from mongodb to elasticsearch without oplog?
I have datasets of 20GB. I am using elasticsearch not for realtime data 
but search on archive database.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch isn't a database, so data can't be "imported" as such. Its an indexing system, so you have to create the indices you require from your source data set.

How you do this will depend on structure and design of your mongo data, and how you want to create you Elasticsearch indices.

There are some options described in this post:

http://techhari.blogspot.ie/2013/11/data-import-options-with-elasticsearch.html

In very simple terms, you need to create a script that will query your mongo data and then place that into a HTTP request that will hit the Elasticsearch API and create the necessary indices.

Comment: Thanks @Garreth.  I am looking for script which regularly pickups data from archive database and index it in elasticsearch. I have seen bulk import in python, but that requires index name and index type in cursor.

Comment: @AnkitaJain have you found your solution?

Comment: Hi @AnkitaJain could you please share your solution?